# Increment a column every time a script is executed

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This shell script is to tabulate and search for SR
n=0 # Initial value for Sl.No
next_n=$[$n+1]
read -p "Enter your SR number : " SR
echo -e "$next_n\t$SR\t$(date)" >> /tmp/cases.txt
```

When I run the script for the first time, I will enter `SR = 123`.
The output will be:

```
1  123   <date>
```

I would like to run the script again, with a new value for `SR = 456`. I would like the output to be:

```
1 123 <date>
2 456 <date>
```

However, my script always print column 1 as `1,1,1,1` because the `n` is getting re-initialized. 
Is there a way to automatically increment column 1 by a factor of 1 every time the script is executed for a new SR value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the value in the first column of the last line of the file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This shell script is to tabulate and search for SR
next_n=$(($(tail -n1 /tmp/cases.txt 2>/dev/null | cut -f1) + 1))
read -p "Enter your SR number : " SR
echo -e "$next_n\t$SR\t$(date)" >> /tmp/cases.txt
```

`cut -f1` selects the first field of the line, fields being sequences of characters separated by tabs.

This also works when the file is empty or non-existent: `next_n` is set to 1 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ -s "/tmp/cases.txt" ] || : > /tmp/cases.txt
next_n=$(expr "$(wc -l < /tmp/cases.txt)" \+ 1)
read -p "Enter your SR number: " SR
printf '%d\t%d\t%s\n' "$next_N" "$SR" "$(date)" >> /tmp/cases.txt
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to add column names to these output. I am able to do this by writing another script and redirecting the output to the destination file. Then running the actual script and appending the entered data. 
I wanted columns like No.  Case Number    Date